# ValueError: unconverted data remains: T00:00:00 - strptime

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have a date string that I am trying to format using python `datetime`.

```
print(datestr, type(datestr)

2006-06-09T00:00:00 <class 'str'>

from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

lastDate = datetime.strptime(datestr, '%Y-%m-%d')

# Calculate Months since
mosLast = (pd.to_datetime('today') - lastDate)/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
```

Traceback:

```
lastDate = datetime.strptime(datestr, '%Y-%m-%d')

  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 352, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
ValueError: unconverted data remains: T00:00:00
```

Comment: try using the first 10 characters like `lastDate[:10]` in the `strptime` function

Comment: Could you please clarify, your input has hours, minutes, seconds specified, why do you expect parsing directive  '%Y-%m-%d' to work? It has to match the input. Also, you mix in pandas; what are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this with:

```
# Format date
lastDate = datetime.strptime(datestr, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
lastDate = datetime.strptime(datestr, '%Y-%m-%d')

# Calculate Months since last sale date
mosLastSale = (pd.to_datetime('today') - lastDate)/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
```